# system-wide git settings

Tags: configuration, system, git, etc, version-control

I would like to set git defaults for all users on my system.

Where can I find the global system-wide configuration?

There is no such file as

```
/etc/gitconfig
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you installed the `git*` package(s) from the default repositories, the system-wide Git configuration is supposed to reside in `/etc/gitconfig` (since `$(prefix)` is empty for those Git installations). See the following [`git-config(1)` manual](//www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) excerpt:

> `--system`
>
> - For writing options: write to system-wide `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig` rather than the repository `.git/config`.
> - For reading options: read only from system-wide `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig` rather than from all available files.
>
>   See also [FILES](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#FILES).
>
> […]
>
> ### FILES
>
> If not set explicitly with `--file`, there are four files where `git config` will search for configuration options:
>
> - `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`
>
>   System-wide configuration file.
>
> […]

If there is no such file, `sudo git config --system <name> <value>` will create it for you. Alternatively you can create it manually with your favourite text editor. This is the same behaviour as for global (`~/.gitconfig`) and local (`$GIT_DIR/config`) Git configuration files